# How to give default value for numeric slider(It should not be random)?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a code for numeric slider. I am able to give min and max value for the slider, but I am not able to specify specific value as default when the page is loaded. I am able to give random value but I want it to be fixed value as we give as value="number".

***I have plan to fetch the default value for slider from database. So please let me know the ways to give it in html tags only.***

```
<meta charset='UTF-8'><meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.9/angular-material.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.9/docs.css'>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" class="sliderdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content style="margin: 16px; padding:16px">

    <div style="margin-top: 50px;"></div>

    <md-slider-container>
      <md-icon md-svg-icon="device:brightness-low"></md-icon>
      <md-slider ng-model="disabled1" aria-label="Disabled 1" md-discrete="" min="1" max="50">
      </md-slider>
      <md-input-container>
        <input type="number" ng-model="disabled1" value="17" min="1" max="50" aria-label="green" aria-controls="green-slider">
      </md-input-container>
    </md-slider-container>
</div>

<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.js'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular-animate.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular-route.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular-aria.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular-messages.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/svg-assets-cache.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.9/angular-material.js'></script>
<script >
  angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.color = {
      red: Math.floor(Math.random() * 255),
      green: Math.floor(Math.random() * 255),
      blue: Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
    };

    $scope.rating1 = 3;
    $scope.rating2 = 2;
    $scope.rating3 = 4;

    $scope.disabled1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);

    $scope.invert = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-init to set the default value to disabled1 scope variable.
See [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/tawisuqomi/edit?html,output)

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-init="disabled1=10" ng-cloak="" class="sliderdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content style="margin: 16px; padding:16px">
    <div style="margin-top: 50px;"></div>
    <md-slider-container>
      <md-icon md-svg-icon="device:brightness-low"></md-icon>
      <md-slider ng-model="disabled1 " aria-label="Disabled 1" md-discrete="" min="1" max="50">
      </md-slider>
      <md-input-container>
        <input type="number" ng-model="disabled1" value="17" min="1" max="50" aria-label="green" aria-controls="green-slider">
      </md-input-container>
    </md-slider-container>
</div>
```